# Tensor product of tempered distributions

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

If $u \in \mathscr S'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $v \in \mathscr S'(\mathbb{R}^m)$ are tempered distributions, then we can identify them with elements of $\mathscr D'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\mathscr D'(\mathbb{R}^m)$ respectively.
This allows us to form the tensor product $u \otimes v$, which is then well-defined as an element of $\mathscr D'(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m)$.

**Question:** Is $u \otimes v$ a tempered distribution? More precisely, does it extend to a sequentially continuous linear form on $\mathscr S(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m)$?

This extension will certainly then be unique by density of $\mathscr C_c^\infty$ in $\mathscr S$, given that it exists.

**Context:** I was wondering if one can extend the Fourier transform identity $\mathscr F(u\otimes v) = \mathscr F u \otimes \mathscr Fv$, which holds for Schwartz functions, to the space of tempered distributions.
However, for this identity to even make sense the tensor product should first be shown to be a tempered distribution.

Comment: Sure. This is the same problem as showing that $f(x) = < u, \phi(x,.)>$ is Schwartz. Also if you take the convolution with some $\varphi \in C^\infty_c$ its growth will be at most polynomial.

Comment: @reuns Indeed, I believe so as well, thanks for the comment. That function is certainly smooth since $\phi$ is, so one only needs to prove that it is rapidly decreasing.

Comment: It is rapidly decreasing because as $x \to \infty$, $\phi(x,.) \to 0$ in the Schwartz space, thus $f(x) \to 0$ (as the pairing with $u$ is continuous), and the same argument holds for the derivatives and multiplication by $x^k$ (which commute with pairing with $u$)

Comment: Nice, it is simpler than I thought it would be. Why don't you post it as an answer?